# Outer Join with Group

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, outer-join

I have a multiple tables that I need to join

```
Customers (CustomerID int, CustomerName varchar(255))
Purchases (CustomerID int, PurchaseDate DateTime, Amt int)
```

MY query is something like that

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, Year(P.PurchaseDate), Month(P.PurchaseDate), Sum(P.Amt)
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN Purchases P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, Year(P.PurchaseDate), Month(P.PurchaseDate)
```

the result are like this

```
CustomerID CustomerName Year Month Amt
1001       Tom          2018 04    200
1001       Tom          2018 01    100
1001       Tom          2017 10    300
1001       Tom          2017 08    400
1002       Matt         2018 03    150
1002       Matt         2018 02    250
1002       Matt         2017 11    350
1002       Matt         2017 08    450
1003       John         2018 04    105
1003       John         2018 03    205
1003       John         2018 02    305
1003       John         2017 12    405
```

Till here everything is ok

But What I actually want to display all months even if there is no data

```
CustomerID CustomerName Year Month Amt
1001       Tom          2018 04    200
1001       Tom          2018 03    0
1001       Tom          2018 02    0
1001       Tom          2018 01    100
1001       Tom          2017 12    0
1001       Tom          2017 11    0
1001       Tom          2017 10    300
1001       Tom          2017 09    0
1001       Tom          2017 08    400
1002       Matt         2018 04    0
1002       Matt         2018 03    150
1002       Matt         2018 02    250
1002       Matt         2018 01    0
1002       Matt         2017 12    0
1002       Matt         2017 11    350
1002       Matt         2017 10    0
1002       Matt         2017 09    0
1002       Matt         2017 08    450
```

I created a new temp table so I can join with

```
DECLARE @Cal AS TABLE (CalYear int , CalMonth int)
INSERT INTO @Cal (CalYear, CalMonth)
VALUES(2018,4)

INSERT INTO @Cal (CalYear, CalMonth)
VALUES(2018,3)

INSERT INTO @Cal (CalYear, CalMonth)
VALUES(2018,2)

...
```

The problem is when I join @Cal in previous query I dont all the months for each customer !!

I tried this

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, Year(P.PurchaseDate), Month(P.PurchaseDate), Sum(P.Amt)
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN Purchases P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @Cal L ON L.CalYear = Year(P.PurchaseDate) AND L.CalYear = Month(P.PurchaseDate)
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, Year(P.PurchaseDate), Month(P.PurchaseDate)
```

any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT  C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, L.CalYear, L.CalMonth, Sum(P.Amt)
FROM    Customers   C
    CROSS JOIN @Cal L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Purchases P ON  C.CustomerID =  P.CustomerID
                                AND L.CalYear    =  Year(P.PurchaseDate) 
                                AND L.CalMonth    =  Month(P.PurchaseDate)
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, L.CalYear, L.CalMonth
```